# ASP Razor MVC 4 Wierd Javascript Formatting

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, formatting

I have built a Intranet ASP Razor MVC 4 website with many JavaScript functions with JQuery. When the website is published a strange transformation occurs with the javascript:

Before publish:

```
$(function()
{
    $("#btnSettings").click(function ()
    {
        $("#dialog-Settings").dialog("open");
    });

    $("#dialog-Settings").dialog(
    {
        resizable: false,
        height: 200,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons:
        {
            "Save": function ()
            {
                var server = $("#serverTitle-Name").text();

                $.get(
                    '@Url.Action("SaveSettings")',
                    { serverName: server },
                    function (responseText)
                    {
                        if (responseText.length > 4)
                        {
                            alert(responseText);
                        }
                    }
                );

                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Cancel: function ()
            {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

After Publish (Live Site):

```
try{if(window.__vwd)__vwd.push(__vwdLid,"","",6672,110);$("#btnSettings").click(function ()
        {var __vwdLid=window.__vwd?++__vwd.nextSid:0;
            try{if(window.__vwd)__vwd.push(__vwdLid,"","",6732,37);$("#dialog-Settings").dialog("open");}finally{if(window.__vwd)__vwd.pop();}
        });}finally{if(window.__vwd)__vwd.pop();}
        try{if(window.__vwd)__vwd.push(__vwdLid,"","",6794,980);$("#dialog-Settings").dialog(
        {
            resizable: false,
            height: 200,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons:
            {
                "Save": function ()
                {var __vwdLid=window.__vwd?++__vwd.nextSid:0;
                    var server = $("#serverTitle-Name").text();
                    try{if(window.__vwd)__vwd.push(__vwdLid,"","\"Save\"",7154,403);$.get(
                        '/Home/ResolveError',
                        { serverName: server },
                        function (responseText)
                        {var __vwdLid=window.__vwd?++__vwd.nextSid:0;
                            try{if(window.__vwd)__vwd.push(__vwdLid,"","",7362,144);if (responseText.length > 4)
                            {
                                try{if(window.__vwd)__vwd.push(__vwdLid,"","",7455,20);alert(responseText);}finally{if(window.__vwd)__vwd.pop();}
                            }}finally{if(window.__vwd)__vwd.pop();}
                        }
                    );}finally{if(window.__vwd)__vwd.pop();}
                    try{if(window.__vwd)__vwd.push(__vwdLid,"","\"Save\"",7581,24);$(this).dialog("close");}finally{if(window.__vwd)__vwd.pop();}
                },
                Cancel: function ()
                {var __vwdLid=window.__vwd?++__vwd.nextSid:0;
                    try{if(window.__vwd)__vwd.push(__vwdLid,"","Cancel",7703,24);$(this).dialog("close");}finally{if(window.__vwd)__vwd.pop();}
                }
            }
        });}finally{if(window.__vwd)__vwd.pop();}
```

Why is ASP transforming my JavaScript like this? And how can I stop it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a ScriptBundle configured (by default in YourWebApp > App_Start > BundleConfig.cs

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

Comment: I don't have an explicit ScriptBundle configured, but it seems as it is on by default. That article is the correct direction though, thanks!